# How to assign icons to `gnotebook()` tabs?

Tags: r, tabs, icons, gwidgets

I am using gWidgets2 to create a tabbed GUI, and I would like each tab to have an associated icon (image).

Consider:

```
require(gWidgets2)
w <- gwindow("notebook example", visible=T)
nb <- gnotebook(container=w)
gbutton("Refresh", label="Refresh", container=nb) ## note label argument
gbutton("Info", label="Info", container=nb)
```

How can I assign the `refresh` icon next to the label of the 1st tab? And the `info` icon to the 2nd tab?

Comment: sorry, lower case `widget`, not upper.

Comment: Thanks. I redefined the fun but I am still unable to get an icon, with a warning message of a `Gtk-CRITICAL assertion`. See UPDATE2.

Comment: Okay, maybe try `icon$widget$parent`

Comment: Indeed that works! The only minor glitch is that the icons end up to the right of the label. How can I have the icon to the *left* of the tab label?

Comment: You can reorder with a call like `box$reorderChild(obj, 0)` where `obj` is the image widget.

Comment: Perfect! This works exactly as hoped for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest GIT of `gWidgets2RGtk2` you can simply do:

```
nb$add_tab_icon(1, "refresh")
nb$add_tab_icon(2, "info")
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can be modified to suit your needs:

```
function add_stock_icon(nb, nm, page) {
    child <- nb$widget$getNthPage(page-1)
    box <- nb$widget$getTabLabel(child)
    icon <- gimage(stock.id=nm)
    box$packStart(icon$Widget)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but failed (see UPDATE1 in OP). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, the following does exactly what needed:

```
add_stock_icon <- function(nb, nm, page, left=TRUE){
    child <- nb$widget$getNthPage(page-1)
    box <- nb$widget$getTabLabel(child)
    icon <- gimage(stock.id=nm)
    box$packStart(icon$widget$parent)
    if(left) box$reorderChild(icon$widget$parent, 0)
}

##add icons to the left of tab labels
add_stock_icon(nb, "refresh", 1)
add_stock_icon(nb, "info", 2)
```