# How to assign tooltips to `gnotebook()` tabs?

Tags: r, tabs, tooltip, gwidgets

I am using gWidgets2 to create a tabbed GUI, and I would like each tab to have an associated tooltip.

Consider:

```
require(gWidgets2)
w <- gwindow("notebook example")
nb <- gnotebook(container=w)
gbutton("Refresh", label="Refresh", container=nb) ## note label argument
gbutton("Info", label="Info", container=nb)
```

From the docs labels can be assigned to tabs via the `label` argument, while this describes [How to assign icons to `gnotebook()` tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706434/how-to-assign-icons-to-gnotebook-tabs). But how can I assign a "Refresh data" tooltip to the 1st tab? And "Data information" to the 2nd tab?

Comment: I just added a `tooltip=` argument to that private `add_tab_icon` method.

Answer (score 0):

With latest GIT of `gWidgets2RGtk2`, you simply need to:

```
nb$add_tab_tooltip(1, "Refresh data")
nb$add_tab_tooltip(2, "Data information")
```